# Passing variable from Ruby as a password for shell

Tags: ruby, shell

I'd like to create a ruby script which acquires variable from user with "gets" and then passes this variable to a Linux shell password prompt.

An example would be:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Which would produce:

```
[sudo] password for username:
```

And there Ruby script should pop in that variable so the update could be executed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You do understand that passing the password on the command-line of a program will instantly make that password available to anyone who can look at the process list, right?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, sudo doesn't accept passwords on standard input by default. You should configure your sudoers file with a `NOPASSWD:` tag for the commands you want to execute without prompting, and invoke sudo with the `-n` flag to ensure that your script doesn't get hung up waiting for input.

If you insist on passing in passwords, see if your sudo supports the `-S` flag, which (on my system) says:

> ```
>    -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
>                the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The
>                password must be followed by a newline character.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, "sudo -S" worked for me just as I wanted it to.