# rails run shell command with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell

I want to run shell command from rails app controller.
My app code is:

```
cmd = "openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/testkey.key 1024"
system cmd
```

than shell will ask me password, so if you run this command from terminal you can input password, but if I run from controller I can't.

I don't want to use rails OPENSSL, for some reasons.

I tried to google but I have no result.

Also I tried something like this:

```
cmd = "openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/testkey.key 1024"
system cmd
system 'echo', '111111Passs'
```

This is not solution of my problem.

My question is:
how to pass password from controller to shell? 
Than how I can submit this command? (simulate press on ENTER on my keyboard)

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514307/passing-variable-from-ruby-as-a-password-for-shell

Comment: Please can you write example ?
it will be something like this ?:
`cmd = "openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/test.key 1024 -S 111111Password"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the passphase through an argument (not recommended):

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/testkey.key -passout pass:SECRET_PASS 1024
```

A more secure option is to write the passphrase to a temporary file and use this:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/testkey.key -passout file:passphrase.txt 1024
```

Answer shamelessly lifted from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300425/8656126) which has much more detail and better explanations.

Comment: please can you explain me what does it mean -passout ?

Comment: "-passout arg    output file pass phrase source" source for the pass phrase

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn("openssl genrsa -des3 -out testfolder/testkey.key 1024") do |reader, writer|
  reader.expect(/Enter pass phrase/)
  writer.puts("<password>")
end
```

Comment: please, explain me this line
` reader.expect(/Enter pass phrase for vendor/testkey.key/)`
thanks

Comment: when the output from the shell matches that string, the password will get inputted into the shell

Comment: so I need to copy exactly terminal answer and paste in this line?

Comment: I think even regex works. so just try something shorter like `Enter pass phrase`